# After including Contact Note Field Access entitlement

Tags: ios, contacts, code-signing-entitlements

When we try to update on top of production build, we are getting the below error:

"This application’s application-identifier entitlement does not match that of the installed application. These values must match for an upgrade to be allowed."

updated....

When i requested for Note Field access we got below response from Apple.

The Team ID and Apple ID you requested have now been given the Contact Note Field Access entitlement and is available for use in your app. The entitlement key and value are listed below:

Entitlement Key: com.apple.developer.contacts.notes
Entitlement Type: Boolean
Entitlement Value: True

To use this special entitlement you must create a new provisioning profile in the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles section of your developer account and select the entitlement after the “Do you need additional entitlements?” page.

After following the above steps. When i downloaded production build and try to update current version we are getting the above error.

Comment: Can you please update with more information about the version, code examples, step to reproduce the error?

Comment: I think this require permission to use this entitlement for an app being put in the App Store.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57442114/ios-13-cncontacts-no-longer-working-to-retrieve-all-contacts